# Changing Image Size In The Content tag

Tags: the-content, template-tags

I am developing a WordPress theme locally and I can't figure out how to get an image to display in a normal size in `the_content()`. At the moment, the images are displaying the same size as my featured image. I tried using the `set_post_thumbnail_size()` to resize the image but still no change.

Has anyone come across the same problem before ?

Any guidance would be great.

Comment: How are you adding the photos in? If you're talking about the `the_post_thumbnail()` function, you will want to specify a size for that function, which is discussed in [The Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail#Thumbnail_Sizes). Otherwise, you may be looking at a CSS issue. Without knowing more, it's hard to say where your problem lies...

Comment: Thanks for the suggest, I think I managed to figure out the problem. My image width and height was set to 100% in my CSS style sheet, which was causing the image to take up the full width of the container.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `set_post_thumbnail_size()` try `add_image_size()`